# Show that the permutation $(1 \space 2 \space 3)$ can not be a cube of any element of $S_n.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Here is my try:

If there exists $a \in S_n$ such that $a^3=(1 \space 2 \space  3)$, then $a^9=e$ where $e$ is identity in $S_n$.

Then $o(a)=9$.

I don't know how to proceed further. Can anyone provide me a hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint, as requested: the order of an element $\sigma$ in $\mathfrak{S}_n$ is the least common multiple of the cycle lengths of $\sigma$.

Comment: How to prove that $9$ can't be LCM of any two integers? If LCM$(a,b)=9$, then $a|9$ and $b|9$ and $9|ab$. Now $3$ and $9$ are candidates for $a$ and $b$. What should I do?

Comment: You should rather prove that if 9 is the lcm of some integers (not necessarily just two) then one of them has to be 9!

Comment: Oh yes indeed. Since only divisors of $9$ are $1,3$ & $9$ so  if any collection of numbers has LCM $9$ then the collection should contain only $3$s and $9$s or either. But since if there are only $3$s then we would have LCM$=3$. That's why the collection should have at least one $9$! Coming back to $S_n$, that means the order $9$ elements contain $3-$cycles and $9-$cycles (disjoint) with at least one $9-$cycle necessarily. So cubing a $9$ order element will make all $3-$cycles disappear and $(a_1 ... a_9)^3=(a_1  a_4 a_7)(a_2 a_5 a_8)(a_3 a_6 a_9)$ which clearly can't be a $3-$cycle. :)

Comment: Exactly! Great!

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake happened when you declared $o(a)=9$. That's not true.

It should read "$|a|$ divides 9". (If you don't mind, I would like to use $|a|$ notion instead of $o(a)$ for order of $a\in S_n$.)

This means $|a|\in \{1,3,9\}$.

Let $|a|=1$. That means $a=\varepsilon$ and hence $(123)=a^3=\varepsilon^3=\varepsilon$ which is contradiction.

Let $|a|=3$. Then $a^3=\varepsilon=(123)$, contradiction again.

And if $|a|=9$ (that means $n\geqslant 9$ otherwise it will be impossible) we can take $a=(a_1a_2\cdots a_9)$ so that $a^3=(a_1a_4a_7)(a_2a_5a_8)(a_3a_6a_9)$. Contradiction once again.